# Use Macro define for declaring multiple version structure in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to solve a problem about a protocol which has multiple version.
Its structure version will continually extend, like the following snippet, the 1.1.2 version may come.

**Original:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct GetReading {
    uint8_t val;
} GetReading_T;


int main()
{
    GetReading_T instaince = {0};
    instaince.val = 0x12c;
    
    printf("%02x\n", instaince.val);

    return 0;
}
```

**After:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MULTI_S(NAME, VERSION) \
typedef struct NAME##_##VERSION { 
    
#define MULTI_E(NAME, VERSION) \
} NAME##_##VERSION##_t; 

MULTI_S(GetReading, 1_1_0)
    uint8_t val;
MULTI_E(GetReading, 1_1_0)

MULTI_S(GetReading, 1_1_1)
    uint16_t val;
MULTI_E(GetReading, 1_1_1)

/*
typedef struct GetReading_1_1_0 {
    uint8_t val;
} GetReading_1_1_0_t;
typedef struct GetReading_1_1_1 {
    uint16_t val;
} GetReading_1_1_1_t;
*/

typedef union GetReading {
    GetReading_1_1_0_t v110;
    GetReading_1_1_1_t v111;
} GetReading_T;


int main()
{
    GetReading_T instaince = {0};
    instaince.v111.val = 0x12c;

    int type = 1;
    if(type == 1) {
        printf("%04x\n", instaince.v111.val);
    } else if (type == 2) {
        printf("%02x\n", instaince.v110.val); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I just wonder if this macro technic is too hard to read and maybe redundant because it can achieve the same by declaring directly. And I found it difficult to warp the macro with the current implementation.

Is there any better practice to solve this kind of problem by C/C++?

Comment: Seems awfully confusing and verbose to me. I don't see what's the issue with putting the names directly as opposed to a macro, because that would be less verbose and easier to understand IMHO.

Comment: Yeah it seems needlessly complicated. If there's only 2 versions, then there's no obvious need for abstraction layers. The old school solution would be a struct with an enum stating type, then a union member containing the data.

Comment: @Lundin Got it, I suspect that it will have around 5 versions for one similar structure in the future, and there is a lot of different structure with many members, originally, I would like to use macro because it will make me easier to know which structures with multiple version have been implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the macro only to generate a name for the structure.
Moreover you can leave the structures untagged because there is alias for them. It would be easier to parse by a human.

```
#define MULTI(NAME, VERSION) NAME##_##VERSION##_t

typedef struct {
  uint8_t val;
} MULTI(GetReading, 1_1_0);

typedef struct {
  uint16_t val;
} MULTI(GetReading, 1_1_1);

typedef union GetReading {
   MULTI(GetReading, 1_1_0) v110;
   MULTI(GetReading, 1_1_1) v111;
} GetReading_T;
```

Comment: Yeah, looks cleaner.

Comment: Additionally, because there is only one place to put the version, I would use no macro at all. Having to know the macro makes the code more difficult to grasp. Anyway :+1:

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any better practice to solve this kind of problem by C/C++?

I strongly recommend using code generation instead of C macros or C++ templates.

Use a script or program to generate the different versions of your protocol. It will be cleaner, easier to understand, faster to compile and easier to maintain.

You can even commit the generated headers so that you only pay the generating price once!

Comment: Great advice. Python and PHP crossed my mind. Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: I've used Python with success in the past. It is installed everywhere nowadays and even Clang has bindings for it if you ever need to parse C code :)